# ExtJS4- Year and month date picker - disable all future dates

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am using a Ext.picker.Month.
Setting maxDate does not disable dates which are grater than the maxDate value, but causes a validation error when selecting one.

How can I disable all future dates?

See [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h5i) -
1. Set maxDate to new Date()
2. Use ExtJS 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating a `MonthPicker`, not a `DatePicker`, yet you are using dozens of config options that are only available for a `DatePicker`.

You can see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/src/Date.js-4.html#Ext.picker.Date-method-createMonthPicker) how to instantiate a `MonthPicker`. As you can see there and especially [in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.picker.Month.html), `MonthPicker` does not provide a config option to disable anything. Also, if you check the `DatePicker` behaviour, you see that `disabledDates` option does not change anything in `MonthPicker`, only *AFTER* the month has been selected, all days in the DatePicker are disabled.

So you would be on your own in implementing `disabledDates` for the `MonthPicker`, which I would do by looking at the code from `DatePicker` and `MonthPicker`, and trying to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one...working on ExtJS 6.0.0. 
>           You need to override **'Ext.picker.Month'** 
>           [find attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYODG.png)
>           Accepted values -
>       new RegExp('(?:)'); ***disable all month/year***
>       new RegExp('^((?!^Apr/2016$|^May/2016$|^Jun/2016$|^Jul/2016$).)*$') ***disable all values other than Apr/May/Jun/Jul 2016***

```
CSS -
.x-monthpicker-disabled {
background-color: #eee !important;
cursor: default !important;
color: #bbb !important;
}


disabledCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'monthpicker-disabled',
disabledMonthYearsRE: null,
disabledMonthYearsText: 'Disabled',

updateBody: function () {
    //default Extjs code
    if (me.rendered) {
        //default Extjs code
        //remove disabled cls and tooltip
        years.removeCls(disabledCls);
        months.set({
            'data-qtip': ''
        });
        years.set({
            'data-qtip': ''
        });
        months.removeCls(disabledCls);
        //default Extjs code
        if (dmyMatch) {
            if (month == null && year == null) {
                months.set({
                    'data-qtip': dmyText 
                });
                months.addCls(disabledCls);
            }
            yrInView = false;
            for (y = 0; y < yLen; y++) {
                yr = yearNumbers[y];
                el = Ext.fly(yearItems[y]);
                if (dmyMatch.toString().indexOf(yr) == -1) {
                    el.dom.setAttribute('data-qtip', dmyText);
                    el.addCls(disabledCls);
                }
                if (yr == year) {
                    yrInView = true;
                }
            }
            if (year != null && yrInView) {
                for (m = 0; m < mLen; m++) {
                    mNo = m;
                    if (mNo < monthOffset) {
                        mNo = mNo * 2;
                    } else {
                        mNo = (mNo - monthOffset) * 2 + 1;
                    }
                    mt = months.elements[mNo];
                    if (dmyMatch.test(mt.text + "/" + year)) {
                        mt.setAttribute('data-qtip', dmyText);
                        mt.className = disabledCls + ' ' + mt.className;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //Add tooltip 'disabled'
                months.set({
                    'data-qtip': dmyText
                });
                months.addCls(disabledCls);
            }
        }
    }
},
//Disable month and year click for disabled values
onMonthClick: function (target, isDouble) {
    var me = this;
    if (!me.disabled && !Ext.fly(target).hasCls(me.disabledCls)) {
         //default Extjs code
    }
},

onYearClick: function (target, isDouble) {
    var me = this;
    if (!me.disabled && !Ext.fly(target).hasCls(me.disabledCls)) {
        //default Extjs code
    }
}
```